# Timeout when browsing network

Tags: networking

This happened suddenly on a pi 4, with no clear reason (system update, maybe?):

When I'm logging on the GUI console, open the Raspbian File Browser (which is pcmanfm), click "go to" => "network", the whole app freezes and, after a time long enough for the system to ask if the process should be killed or not, comes back with an error message saying it timed out (literal translation would be "waiting delay exceeded").

I usually access this pi through SSH and with smbclient, I can access to the network pretty decently, but I could really use the file browser in this situation to save time and hassle.

I tried:

- rebooting
- `sudo dpkg -reconfigure pcmanfm`
- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall pcmanfm`
- Triggering the error and looking for something in the /var/log directory that would give a clue... Alas, not a single change in any of the log files!

The only thing that may or may not be telling something is that when (in pcmanfm) clicking "go to" => "connect to server", the only server "Type" are SSH, FTP and WebDAV.
I may be mistaking, but shouldn't there be "SMB" in the list?

That's really annoying, because what I do on the GUI console is precisely things I can't do easily remotely.

I know there are other file browsers but I'd like to keep this setup as simple as possible, with the least possible changes from the vanilla Raspbian stuff.

**Update**

Starting off with latest RaspOS64, fresh download from the SD image wizard to be sure I've not been messing with something.
pcmanfm still hang.

Tried installing Thunar... Also hangs as soon I try to access the network.

Other machines on this network are Windows (7, 10), Linux, Android, routers and internet boxes.

All can be reached from the command line (some via their NETBIOS name, but one of the internet boxes surprisingly answers only on its IP).

Mystery still not solved...

Answer (score 0):

Problem vanished by itself but still no explanation.

What I did:

- Completely disconnect **everything** from the Pi (I tried with a leftover PI 3 and a 32bit Raspbian on another SD card, just to prove myself I was not going nuts)
- Let it **seat unpowered** to meditate on it's behavior (about **5 minutes**, that's the time it took to check the other board, no surprise: everything was fine)
- **Plug everything back** in this order if it matters somehow: Ethernet, HDMI, USB Power, USB peripherals (in my case a powered USB hub with keyboard, mouse and DSLR camera)

Again, I have no clue what happened, and I tried to reboot and even cold boot a few times, but nothing did it until I left the board unplugged & unpowered for 5 minutes.

That's great, but I surely would like to understand...